# Image dimensions validation in data-parsley

Tags: javascript, php, json, parsley.js

I want to validate image Dimensions using data-parsley.

I tried the code below but it don't works.

```
data-parsley-dimensions-options='{
    "min_width": "100", 
    "max_width": "100", 
    "min_height": "100", 
    "max_height": "100", 
    "width": "100", 
    "height": "100", 
    "ratio": "1:1" }'
```

How I can solve this? There is no backend error displayed :(

This is the [reference link](http://parsley-laraextras.happydemon.xyz/rules/file).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/laravel-parsley.js"></script>
```

this js file not add after add this will be work :P